# Why Only One contact selected in AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android

I want to select multiple contact from autocompletetextview. But right now I can able to select only one contact .

Code is below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mPeopleList;
private SimpleAdapter mAdapter;
private AutoCompleteTextView mTxtPhoneNo;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mPeopleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    PopulatePeopleList();
    mTxtPhoneNo = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.mmWhoNo);
    mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mPeopleList, R.layout.custcontview,
            new String[] { "Name", "Phone", "Type" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontNo, R.id.ccontType });
    mTxtPhoneNo.setAdapter(mAdapter);



    mTxtPhoneNo.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View arg1, int index,
                long arg3) {
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) av.getItemAtPosition(index);

            String name  = map.get("Name");
            String number = map.get("Phone");
            mTxtPhoneNo.setText(""+name+"<"+number+">");


        }



    });

}

public void PopulatePeopleList() {
    mPeopleList.clear();
    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (people.moveToNext()) {
        String contactName = people.getString(people
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String contactId = people.getString(people
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String hasPhone = people
                .getString(people
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

        if ((Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) > 0)){
            // You know have the number so now query it like this
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,
            null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()){
                //store numbers and display a dialog letting the user select which.
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(
                phones.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                String numberType = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();
                NamePhoneType.put("Name", contactName);
                NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber);
                if(numberType.equals("0"))
                    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Work");
                    else
                    if(numberType.equals("1"))
                    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Home");
                    else if(numberType.equals("2"))
                    NamePhoneType.put("Type",  "Mobile");
                    else
                    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Other");
                    //Then add this map to the list.
                    mPeopleList.add(NamePhoneType);
            }
            phones.close();
        }
    }
    people.close();
    startManagingCursor(people);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int index, long arg){
    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) av.getItemAtPosition(index);
    Iterator<String> myVeryOwnIterator = map.keySet().iterator();
    while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
        String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
        String value=(String)map.get(key);
        mTxtPhoneNo.setText(value);
    }
}


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/mmWhoNo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="To...." 
    android:textColor="#A5AA0000"
    >
</AutoCompleteTextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**custcontview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ccontName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#A5AA0000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ccontNo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/ccontName"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#A5AA0000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ccontType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/ccontNo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#A5AA0000" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a logic for selecting multiple contacts using listview, we can simply use `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`. The code is as same as for the `AutoCompleteTextView`. Through this we can select multiple contacts.

Comment: I used as per your suggestion. But now no listview for select contact.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`, instead.

```
mTxtPhoneNo = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.mmWhoNo);
mTxtPhoneNo.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

Hope it helps!